# How to use pickled scikit-learn model in Jython UDF for Pig?

Tags: python, apache-pig, scikit-learn, jython

I have trained a MultinomialNB model from scikit-learn and now I want to unleash it on many, many json text files on a cluster on S3. I pickled the model (call it "nb.pickle"). How do I load that in a Pig script and use it? Say I have a file with lines of text, each one needs to be classified as spam or ham:

```
    "im bored tonight, come chat with me",
    "hi good looking msg me sometime",
    "I'm walking the dog",
    "check me out",
    "I went to the store earlier",
    "here much at all but im always on there at i get on there alot more, my id is orangewolf77",
    "I like to play baseball",
    "what are you doing?",
    "i had a picture on my profile did u not see it?",
    "look at my b00bs",
    "go to my website http://we.scam.u
    "you are so pretty"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jython cannot use numpy, scipy and scikit-learn as they all have native compiled extensions that are not supported in Jython. It is therefore not possible to use scikit-learn models in Jython nor to load them from a pickle file.

What you could do it introspect the code of the MNB class to understand which parameters to export (e.g. in a json file) and rewrite a new predict method that can compute predictions from those fixed parameters in Jython.

Alternatively you can install CPython, numpy, scipy and scikit-learn on your hadoop nodes (e.g. with the Anaconda distribution) and call into scikit-learn via the hadoop streaming interface.